# Can composer overwrite existing files?

Tags: magento, composer-php

I have a general question of composers handling with existing files.
I got a new project with some repositories and a composer.json & -lock file.

When I try to run composer install everything is fine.
But the result is definitly wrong.

The reason:
The main project folder contains a folder with 6 files among other things.
But one of the repositories in the composer.json also has the same folder with some files which are equal to the main project folder.

So instead that composer is returning an error it creates the folder under the existing folder and copy alle files inside it.
That project is a magento shop and these files have to have a fixed structure. So this job what composer is doing is wrong.

My question here, can composer overwrite existing files or warn me when there are already files in the same folder, so that the mapping can't be succeded?